# How do I echo the json data in php?

Tags: php, json

I want to echo a certain part of json in php. I don't know if the json data is valid or invalid.

I have tried the below code:

```
$get = get_content('domain');
$json = file_get_contents($get);
$decode = json_decode($json);
$final = $decode->count;
echo $final;
```

The json data which I get from an URL is:
`{"15":{"xy":{"cost":6,"count":235}}}`

I expect to see only the 235 part. This data keeps on changing. Sometimes the number 6 in the cost can vary as well.

EDIT: Fixed some code.
EDIT1: Actually the data was already a string so just used echo substr($get, 30, 3); to achieve the results.

Comment: `$final = $decode->{15}->xy->count;`

Comment: Hello @Nick I tried your solution but I don't get the output echoed.

Comment: https://3v4l.org/tJj0n

Comment: Hmm. I think file_get_contents isn't parsing the data.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it should work

```
echo  $decode[15]['xy']['count'];
```

Comment: Tried it and there was no output. May be the data from the domain isn't json. If possible can you show how do I get the same data using explode and regex? Thanks.

Comment: Please change $arr to $decode. see edited answer

Comment: Still I couldn't get the output.
I have edited the original post to include the domain for testing. Please check it.

Comment: I achieved the output. Actually the data was already a string and not json.
I used echo substr($get, 30, 3); to extract the content.